# Problem running Python code in Jupyter Notebook: GoodReadsScraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, python-idle

I would like to start by letting you know that I am a layperson. I only started working with Python a few weeks ago, so I am new to this and am not yet familiar with quite a lot of the necessary terminology. I would be very grateful for your help!

I want to try out Omar Einea's Goodreads Reviews Scraper (https://github.com/OmarEinea/GoodReadsScraper). I followed his instructions and installed beautifulsoup4, langdetect, selenium and lxml using pip.
I copy-pasted part of his code from reviews.py to a Jupyter Notebook to test it out and ran the following cell:

```
from Tools import SafeThread
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from langdetect import detect
from Browser import Browser
from Writer import Writer
```

However, I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-4dc46ca353f6> in <module>
----> 1 from Tools import SafeThread
      2 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
      3 from langdetect import detect
      4 from Browser import Browser
      5 from Writer import Writer

ImportError: cannot import name 'SafeThread' from 'Tools' (unknown location)
```

I thought that perhaps I had to install tools first, so I ran
Python Code:

```
pip install tools
```

in the command line, but I received the message that it had already been installed:

```
C:\Users\Lore>pip install Tools
Requirement already satisfied: Tools in c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (0.1.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pytils in c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from Tools) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from Tools) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from Tools) (4.4.2)
```

Do you have any ideas on how I might be able to solve this problem?

I also have another question. So far I have only worked in/with jupyter notebooks. Is there a better way/place to write and run my Python scripts/commands?

I tried running the entire code from "Reviews.py", by opening it in IDLE and clicking on "run", but that just gave me this:

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
======= RESTART: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\GoodReadsScraper-master\Reviews.py ======
>>>
```

Thank you in advance for your kind help and understanding!

Comment: As far as running your code in general, if you primarily just want to run scripts, you can run those in the more traditional way on a command line with `python <name_of_script.py>` or similar.  You can still run your scripts in a notebook with `%run <name_of_script.py>`. Developing in scripts tends to make your code more portable & improve development/reproducibility. You may wish to read the section 'Joel’s complaints about notebooks' [here](https://yihui.org/en/2018/09/notebook-war/). But for early learning, you can focus on the basics & improve your development practices as you code more.

Comment: IDLE may have worked to run your script. `Reviews.py` just imports some items and defines a class. It isn't going to generate any output. You may be better off focusing on `Sample.py` when testing.

Comment: I ran out of room above or I'd have added that using IDLE to run scripts is good, too. Years ago I had trouble installing it on a Mac where I didn't have admin privileges, but you can easily use command line for running Python on Mac and linux. PythonAnywhere.com has free basic accounts that give you access to a command-line like interface but for 'free' accounts they only allow outbound traffic to specific, whitelisted URLs, and so it wouldn't be a good match with your current project unless what you need happens to be on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Tools' being referenced in `Review.py` is [this script called 'Tools' in the repository you reference](https://github.com/OmarEinea/GoodReadsScraper/blob/master/Tools.py).

What you installed with `pip install tools` is something not related to that.  You can see it [here](https://pypi.org/project/tools/).

You'd have an easier time if you download all the code in [the repository](https://github.com/OmarEinea/GoodReadsScraper) and then try running things while your working directory is set to that directory. In a notebook you can use `pwd` to print your working directory. You can use `%cd` to change it.